# Getting Coordinates to UINavigationController into the showDetails Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I have a map view with pins annotations into it. I need to pass to the detail view the coordinates of a pin when the user press the disclosure button of the pin information. How can I get the coordinates of the pin when I am into the showDetails method? I am using the next code.

```
- (void)showDetails:(id)sender {

 DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil ];

    // HERE I NEED TO PASS THE COORDINATES OF THE PIN TO THE DETAILVIEWCONTROLLER.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 [detailViewController release];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

 // If it's the user location, just return nil.
 if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
  return nil;
 else { // Handles the other annotations.
  // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
  static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
  MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

  if (!pinView) {
   // If an existing pin view was not available, creates one.
   MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
   customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
   customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

   // Adds a detail disclosure button.
   UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
   [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

   return customPinView;
  } else
   pinView.annotation = annotation;
 }

 return nil;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot give you a working code solution right now since i don't have my mac here. But I can tell you about a possible approach.

Create a method in DetailViewController that populates its attributes, so you can call it from showDetails, before you push it. So the sequence of events would be like this.

Click on disclosure button -> showDetails called -> DetailViewController created and populated -> push DetailViewController

Hope this helped you

Comment: Hi Francisco. I am using a similar solution. Create a class variable that holds the coordinates of the last annotation clicked. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can your UIButton button custom like this :

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton {
```

CLLocationCoordinate2D pinCoordinate;
    }

Now in your viewForAnnotation :

```
// Adds a detail disclosure button.
CustomButton *rightButton = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
rightButton.pinCoordinate = annotation.coordinate
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

And finally to get the coordinate in the showDetails method :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCoord = ((CustomButton*)sender).pinCoordinate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer MathieuF. I have tried your solution but it doesn't work. I create your button and a setter method into the m file, but when I assign annotation.coordinate to righButton.pinCoordinate, I get this exception '-[UIButton setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b70120'. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What's the type of your right button ? Have you put this in your code : CustomButton *rightButton = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; ?